# Add up Repeated Items (String) in a Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have two list boxes. User selects an item from one listbox and press a button which add selected value to the second listbox.                                     I want to addup the repeated item when user select an item from first listbox multiple times and add it to second listbox. If he/she selected item1 twice, the second listbox should automatically add an item "2 X items1" to the listbox and remove the repeated items from listbox2. Following is my try but i dont know how to progress further. Thanks

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       for (int i = 0; i <= listBox2.Items.Count; i++)

           if (listBox2.Items[0].ToString()==listBox2.Items[i].ToString())                 {
                }
    }
```

Comment: if ( ! listBox2.Items.Contains(item) )
         {
              listBox2.Items.Add(item);
         }

Comment: thanks. it listbox2 doesn't contain item, add item to listbox2. i understand that. What about if listbox already contain value to be added, add up the number of times its present in listbox2 and replace item with (number of times) x item...